# create 3 dimensional array with different lengths

Tags: arrays, r, grouping

I am a beginner of R.
I want to create a 3 dimensional array but I can not define the length of each dimension. 
I am analysing students' marks in a class. There are 10 classes but it has a different number of students. And "Grade" will be 100-90, 89-80, 79-70... until there will be any student who got the relevant marks.
I was going to use a couple of for-loops with the multiple array.
If I create a 3 dim array,

```
arr<-array(data, dim=c(??,??,??)), dimnames= list("class","grade","average Marks") )
```

Comment: Can you clarify why you want this as three dimensional data? How is grade and average marks different dimensions, when it's based on the same data?

Comment: this is how the data like: class= 1:10
Class 1/Student marks: 89, 87, 90, 95, 76, 78, 45, 65, 88, 95, 56, 34, 93, 92,100, ..
I wanted to know  first: how many students are in each "Grade" group 
and Second: the average marks of each group in each class.
So I was going to use 3 dimemsional including "Grade" then the results will have arr[class, grade, avr].
They will be linked each other. For example class 1-> grade 90~100-> some value, class1->grade 80~89->some value... and Class 2-> grade 90~100->some value..

Answer (score 4):

You really do not want to use a matrix for this. A dataframe allows you to have a mixture of data types.

```
clasIDs <- c("Firsthour", "Secondhour", "Thirdhour")
class.size <-c(3, 5, 2)  # small sizes for illustration
cls.frame <- data.frame(clasID=rep(clasIDs, class.size), 
                      student.ID = unlist(sapply(class.size, function(x) seq(from=1, to=x))),
                      grade=factor(rep(NA,10) , levels=c("100-90", "89-80", "79-70")) )

> cls.frame
       clasID student.ID grade
1   Firsthour          1  <NA>
2   Firsthour          2  <NA>
3   Firsthour          3  <NA>
4  Secondhour          1  <NA>
5  Secondhour          2  <NA>
6  Secondhour          3  <NA>
7  Secondhour          4  <NA>
8  Secondhour          5  <NA>
9   Thirdhour          1  <NA>
10  Thirdhour          2  <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Array are of fixed dimensions. You could use the maximum along each dimension and allocate that along with `NA` to fill in.

Lists are the alternative for varying lengths, and even different component types.

Comment: ah..yes, I think I've read something like 'fixed'dimension on array.. thank you.